# How can I improve this Emacs lisp function?

Tags: emacs, elisp

The intent is to use `git grep` as the command for `M-x grep`, and all the buffer benefits that come along with it. Desired functionality:

- It reads the word/thing at point as the default value (done, sort of)
- It reads the current region as the default argument if a region is set.

The following is the code I have so far:

```
(defun bw-read-string-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((word (word-at-point)))
    (set-text-properties 0 (length word) nil word)
    word))

(defun bw-git-grep (search-str)
  "Uses `git-grep` to find `search-str`"
  (interactive
   (list
    (read-string (format "Search for (%s): " (bw-read-string-at-point)))))
  (let ((search-str (if (= (length search-str) 0)
                        (bw-read-string-at-point) search-str)))
    (grep (concat "git --no-pager grep -i -I -nH --no-color --extended-regexp " search-str))))
```

I feel like the `interactive` bit there is quite clumsy and could be made much better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, it looks pretty good.  Except you should use the `default' argument of`read-string, and the `interactive` in `bw-read-string-at-point` should not be there.  Or better yet, just use `grep-tag-default`.
Here's how I'd tweak it:

```
(defun bw-git-grep (search-str)
  "Uses `git-grep` to find `search-str`"
  (interactive
   (let ((default (grep-tag-default)))
    (list
     (read-string (format "Search for (default %s): " default)
                  nil nil default))))
  (grep (concat "git --no-pager grep -i -I -nH --no-color --extended-regexp " search-str)))
```

Comment: Where does `grep-tag-default` come from? I can't find it in Emacs 24.2. EDIT: actually never mind, got it. For some reason `C-h f` couldn't find it.

Comment: Ah, yes, you probably need to `(require 'grep)` to make sure that `grep-tag-default` is defined.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `read-from-minibuffer` instead of `read-string`:

```
(defun bw-git-grep (pattern)
  (interactive
   (list
    (read-from-minibuffer
     "Search for: "
     (if (region-active-p)
         (buffer-substring-no-properties (region-beginning) (region-end))
       (thing-at-point 'word)))))

  (let* ((grep-command "git --no-pager grep -i -I -nH --no-color --extended-regexp ")
         (command      (concat grep-command pattern))
         (grep-use-null-device nil))
    (grep command)))
```

Also, you probably need to ensure that `grep-use-null-device` is nil to avoid `grep` appending `/dev/null` to your command (which `git` doesn't seem to like much)

Comment: I would advise against it: `read-string` is generally preferable to `read-from-minibuffer`, and in your above example, `read-from-minibuffer' offers no benefit.

Comment: @Stefan I was not very familiar with the full interface of `read-string`, but you're right: `read-from-minibuffer` offers no benefit in this case. However, I haven't found anything in the documentation that would imply that `read-string` is preferable to `read-from-minibuffer`. Would you have any source documenting this?

Comment: No, indeed, it's not yet very documented.  But `read-from-minibuffer` is a low-level function on top of which the other `read-*` functions are implemented.  In the case of `read-string` the main difference is the handling of `default` which you didn't use but which is the recommended way to provide a default in Emacs (instead of `initial`).

Comment: Thanks for `grep-use-null-device` tip!